# Having trouble displaying a single field from database using MySQL API in C

Tags: mysql, c, database

I'm working on a school project at the moment and I need to fetch values from a database to a Raspberry PI which then needs to act accordingly (turn on light, open door etc..) depending on the values.

I've finished my Java programming course but I'm still very much a beginner in C (started a week ago). There might be very obvious problems with the code that I'm just not seeing.

I've been using the MySQL API in C to update the values in the database but I'm having problems fetching values. 
Here's the code I'm using:

```
#include <my_global.h>
#include <mysql.h>
#include <stdio.h>


int main()
{      
MYSQL *conn;

conn = mysql_init(NULL);

if (!mysql_real_connect(conn, "localhost", "user", "password", 
      "testdb", 0, NULL, 0)) 
{
  fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", mysql_error(conn));
exit(1);
}    

if (mysql_query(con, "SELECT sensorwaarde FROM Sensordata WHERE  samplenummer = 4")) 
{
  exit(1);
}

MYSQL_RES *result = mysql_store_result(con);

if (result == NULL) 
{
  exit(1);
}

int num_fields = mysql_num_fields(result); 
int value;
MYSQL_ROW row;

while ((row = mysql_fetch_row(result))) 
{ 
  value = *row[0] 
}
printf("%d", value);
mysql_free_result(result);
mysql_close(con);

return 0;
}
```

The database I'm connecting to holds the table "Sensordata" which I'm fetching from. It has 3 columns and 2 rows, I'm trying to retrieve the value which is held in the 3rd column and the 1st row (holds value 10). I checked to see if there's a way to simply fetch data from a single field in the table but there seems to be no simple way to do this.

This code compiles properly but it prints the value 49, which is nowhere in my database.

Can anyone help me out on this one?

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: When you create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to show us, it's important that it's actually *verifiable*, i.e. that it builds (unless you're asking about build errors of course).

Comment: As for your problem, remember that `row` (in your program) is an array of *strings*. The value you get, `49`, happens to be the [ASCII value](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/ascii) of the character `'1'`.

Comment: So instead of using an int to hold the value should I make a char array to hold it? Follow up question, since I need to use this value in further programs to give the system instructions, how do I make the value an actual integer?

Comment: You already *have* a "char array": `row[0]`. Use a function such as `strtol` to convert it to an integer.

Comment: Nice, it worked! Thanks a bunch man.